# Create repository button disabled on GitHub

Tags: git, github, repository

I am using macOS version 11.2.2 BigSur. I don't seem to be able to create a GitHub repository on the web (I am using safari). The button is greyed out or you say it as disabled.
There is no other problem in naming, storage etc.
Please suggest me some solutions.

[image: here is a image of the disabled button]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot where the button is disabled and all details are visible.

Comment: i am in the same version of MacOS. Its working fine for me. Just remove the browser cache and try again. Make sure the repo name is valid too.

Comment: @AhamedSafnaj tried doing so, no improvement.

Comment: try with incognito/private mode

Comment: also replace the screenshot by having a repo name

Comment: You can only create a repository after entering a name...

Comment: same here. It looks pretty buggy to me

Answer (score 27):

**Try creating a repository with .gitignore without any template makes create repository button disabled.**

**.gitignore template: None -> create Repository button is disabled.**

[image]

**Now either deselect the option or select a template, will make the button enabled.**

[image]

Comment: So silly, if you ask me. Unchecking the `.gitignore` option also fixes this.

Comment: Thanks Fizz, i have already mentioned that too "Now either deselect the option or select a template, will make the button enabled"

Answer (score 15):

Try to remove the disabled attribute of the button using developer tools (inspect). It works for me.

Comment: This is what we call brute force approach

Comment: unbelievable solution which actually worked

Answer (score 3):

The only required fields are:

1. Owner
2. Repository Name

Once those 2 fields have been filled out the button will be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by pressing **Tab** until the button was selected. Then **Enter** submitted the form.